Gitlab + M architecture + Tart to build Android apps?
Does anyone have a recipe for building Android apps (requires Android SDK command line tools + more) using https://tart.run/ ? For instance if there is an official Tart image ready to use (with JDK / Android SDK command line tools, etc)?
I am using Gitlab and would like to reduce overhead as much as possible (not having to build a Tart image for every Gitlab job). Building a Tart image in the first job in the pipeline and passing it as an artifact also adds overhead as the large file has to be transferred every time.
